# How to display sprite in the right place regardless of screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using "Sprite Kit", and I have a node displayed at a certain point. It looks great on the "4 inch screen", but it's off on the "3.5 inch screen" and REALLY off on the iPad's iPhone simulator. I set the location like this:

```
    myNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height - self.size.height/10);
```

So, I would think it should display properly regardless of size, but it's not. I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong, and I think (and hope) there should be a simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display it to top left corner,

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: myNode.size.width * 0.5,
                          y: self.size.height - myNode.size.height * 0.5)
```

To middle left,

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: myNode.size.width * 0.5, 
                          y: (self.size.height - myNode.size.height) * 0.5);
```

To bottom left corner,

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: myNode.size.width * 0.5,
                          y: myNode.size.height * 0.5);
```

To middle bottom,

```
 myNode.position  = CGPoint(x: (self.size.width - myNode.size.width) * 0.5,
                            y: myNode.size.height * 0.5);
```

To right bottom corner,

```
 myNode.position  = CGPoint(x: (self.size.width - myNode.size.width) * 0.5,
                            y: myNode.size.height * 0.5);
```

To middle right,

```
myNode.position  = CGPoint(x: self.size.width - myNode.size.width * 0.5,
                           y: (self.size.height - myNode.size.height) * 0.5);
```

To top right,

```
myNode.position  = CGPoint(x: self.size.width  - myNode.size.width * 0.5,
                           y: self.size.height - myNode.size.height * 0.5);
```

To middle screen,

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: (self.size.width - myNode.size.width) * 0.5,
                          y: (self.size.height - myNode.size.height) * 0.5);
```

Comment: I typed it straightly from iphone so if anyone would edit and format it nicely that would make it more readable.

Comment: This is helpful for displaying in those positions, but I need it in a position that's not one of those. I need it like an inch down from the top of the screen on the 4 inch screen, and whatever the equivalent is on the 3.5 inch screen.

Comment: So keep some offset values to one of those you need from above. If you want it to be 10 pooints from top then, choose the top one from the given one and subtract the inset value. It should work the same way for boyh sizes. If you want different inset for different sze define one inset for one size and another for another and based on the screensize use the appropriate inset.

Comment: Is there a preset way to set different inset values for different sizes? Or do I just use if statements?

Comment: There are a couple of changes I'd make with this... For instance `self.size.width/2 - myNode.size.width/2` I'd do `(self.size.width - myNode.size.width) * 0.5` for efficiency. Etc...